# jQuery - fade item in/out whilst retaining flow layout

Tags: jquery, css

I have a list of items in my web application; each of these has a set of command buttons arrayed beneath it.

To keep the interface clean, these buttons only show up when you hover over the item. The buttons are wrapped in a tag which has the following CSS attribute: `visibility: hidden`

This preserves the *layout* - so that the list items don't jump around as the buttons are revealed.

What I want to do is fade the buttons in/out using jQuery. However, the default methods (`fadeIn(), fadeOut()`) seem to use `display: none`, which removes the buttons from the flow.

What I need is a way to fade them in or out using the `visibility` attribute. So, before I embark on a search, does anyone know of an obvious way of doing this that I'm missing?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create empty wrapper DIVs (with dimensions specified) for the elements you're fading. Fade what's inside. Alternately, you can fade it to 1%, so it will still take up space, but be barely visible.

Comment: I think this is probably what I'll end up doing; although I think I'll do it by setting a min-height on the containing list element...

Answer (score 15):

Roll your own fadeout, like this:

```
$(this).animate({opacity: "0.0"});
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0); should do it, the docs say nothing about setting display. Only fadeOut() has the display: none; set in the docs, but give me just a moment and I'll test it out.